# Inverse transformation corr coefficients to initial value

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, correlation

Let's work with classic dataset with iris
`data(iris`)
When I conduct Pearson corr analysis, i have these corr coefficients

```
             SEPALLEN   SEPALWID    PETALLEN    PETALWID
SEPALLEN    1,000000    -0,117570   0,871754    0,817941
SEPALWID    -0,117570   1,000000    -0,428440   -0,366126
PETALLEN    0,871754    -0,428440   1,000000    0,962865
PETALWID    0,817941    -0,366126   0,962865    1,000000
```

So is there the way to perform inverse transformation, namely from corr coefficients to initial value of variables?

Comment: Have you heard of Anscombe’s quartet?

Comment: @MauritsEvers, no. i did not hear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot extract details of data of correlation data, only the general character of correlation between two columns. If Person's coefficient is positive than there is a increasing tendency, if negative then decreasing one. We can visualize it with correlation plot:

```
data(iris)
ibrary(PerformanceAnalytics)
chart.Correlation(iris[, 1:4], histogram=TRUE, pch=19)
```

As you can see below each upper trianglar number matches with a graph in a lower triangle. In fact the `cor` function transforms 600 entries in `iris` (1-4 columns) data into just 5 unique numbers. So inverse transformation from 5 numbers into 600 numbers in an unambigous way is not possible:
[image: coorrleatin]

Comment: well, what if i know mean and sigma of each variable, can i use this info to generate sample for 4 variable which gives similar corr corf?